# Accessing the data inside an object when you dont know the name of the key

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, nested-object

I have a set of data where the key on the data is not predictable. I am trying to read the nested object but I cant seem to access it so I can check the value of the next key `Physicians` or `NonPhysicians`. I tried using the key of the nested value to access it but it only returns undefined. When I console out `item` i get the expected values and when I console out `org` I get the keys on the objects so im not sure whats going wrong here.

```js
const NEWRATES = {
  standard: [
    {
      "ORG A": {
        Physicians: {
          telehealth: {
            weekdayEncounters: 15,
            weeknightEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 17.25,
            holidayEncounters: 17.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        NonPhysicians: {
          telehealth: {
            orgName: "Standard",
            weekdayEncounters: 15,
            weeknightEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 17.25,
            holidayEncounters: 17.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        date: "07-2021",
        orgName: "some org",
        ltc: false,
      },
    },
    {
      "ORG B": {
        Physicians: {
          telehealth: {
            weekdayEncounters: 15,
            weeknightEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 17.25,
            holidayEncounters: 17.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        NonPhysicians: {
          telehealth: {
            orgName: "Standard",
            weekdayEncounters: 15,
            weeknightEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 17.25,
            holidayEncounters: 17.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        date: "07-2021",
        orgName: "some org",
        ltc: false,
      },
    },
  ],
  ltc: [
    {
      Infinity: {
        Physicians: {
          associates: {
            roundingHours: 10,
            onCallHours: 10,
            weekdayEncounters: 16,
            weeknightEncounters: 17.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 18.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 19.25,
            holidayEncounters: 20.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        NonPhysicians: {
          associates: {
            roundingHours: 0,
            onCallHours: 0,
            weekdayEncounters: 15,
            weeknightEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendDayEncounters: 16.25,
            weekendNightEncounters: 17.25,
            holidayEncounters: 17.25,
            stipend: 0,
          },
        },
        date: "07-2021",
        orgName: "some org",
        ltc: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};

const sortData = Object.values(NEWRATES);
  const NEWfiltered = !!NEWRATES && sortData;
  const byProviderType =
    !!NEWfiltered &&
    NEWfiltered.map((item, idx) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        let list = [];
        let org = Object.keys(item[i]).toString();

        console.log(item[org]);
      }
    });
```

Comment: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Here is a stackblitz with this running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6gbjyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You need to keep going one level deeper.

```
// Your Code Now
console.log(item[org]);

// SHOULD BE
console.log(item[i][org]);
```

Make this update, and you will see it working. [HERE is a working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6gbjyk) on stackblitz.